# Add to subproject to gradle jar

Tags: java, gradle

How can I add a subproject referenced using `project(':api')` to the jar gradle builds?

This is the `build.gradle` of my main project. The subproject is includes as git submodule and has a similar buildscript.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5
version = '1.0'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes('Main-Class': '..........')
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/jfxrt.jar')
    compile project(':api')
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

Comment: See the `multi-project builds` chapter in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html), and the samples in the full Gradle distribution.

Comment: I've tried that but I'm not able to get the classpath of the subproject added to the main jar.

Comment: So the build already works, and your question is how to create a fat Jar?

Comment: The build works just fine. The problem is that launching the jar causes an `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` because the classes of the subproject are missing.

Comment: Have you resolved this problem?

Comment: Yes, just look at my own answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out on my own.

Include the source of a subproject in the main jar:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir project(':api').file('src/main/java')
        }
    }
}
```

Including the classes of a jar in the main jar:

```
jar {
    from zipTree('libs/abc.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add classpath to your manifest file. You need to have directory (example below uses "lib") to keep jar files on which your project depends.

Try modifying your "jar" block in gradle build to something like this. I have some addition properties just for demonstration. But the important one is Class-Path

```
jar {
    manifest.attributes(
        'Class-Path': lib/api.jar
        'Built-By': System.getProperty('user.name'),
        'Built-JDK': System.getProperty('java.version'),
        'Built-OS': System.getProperty('os.name'),
        'Built-DATE': buildDate,
    )
}
```

I hope it helps to fix your issue.

Comment: That isn't really what I was looking for. I would like the source of the subproject to be **include** in the main jar, so that a jar containing the **classes of both projects** is built.

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest case, a fat Jar can be created as follows:

main/build.gradle:

```
jar {
    from configurations.runtime
}
```

There are other, more robust solutions, such as the [gradle-one-jar](https://github.com/rholder/gradle-one-jar) plugin for "main" method style applications.